# Arrays not working when consuming SAP Webservices

Tags: c#

I am currently consuming a SAP Webservice but the only object that is returned with values are those without child items.

I have no influence in how the SAP Web-service is set up so have no idea if it is correct, they have simply sent me the link and the XML which looks fine.

I have had to go into Reference.cs and amend the class due to a Property being named System as below but as the function seems to work I don't think this has any bearing on the issue:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
```

to

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=global::System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
```

I have tried changing the web-config to see if the binding parameters were effecting it.
I have tried changing the Collection Type in the Web Service configuration to use System.Array, Generic Lists.

The classes that don't work look like this:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form= System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("item", Form= System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]

   
        public Humans[] People{
            get {
                return this.crowd;
            }
            set {
                this.crowd= value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Humans");
            }
        }
```

The one class that does work looks like this:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute( Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=2)]

    public HandShake Return {
        get {
            return this.returnField;
        }
        set {
            this.returnField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Return");
        }
    }
```

and the XML looks like this:

```
<n0:SAPFunction>
   <Humans>
      <item>
         <name>Joe</name>
         <age>13</age>
         <town>The Shire</town>
      </item>
      <item>...</item>
   </Humans>
   <Return>
      <Id>0</Id>
      <Message>People Found</Message>
      <System/>
   </Return>
</n0:SAPFunction>
```

So basically the Array classes should all have `items` but I just get a load of empty arrays and the HandShake class with the return message values.

Thoughts please?

So the XML that the SAP team send me when I do a call looks good but any class that expects items i.e.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("item", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
```

just doesn't work. The classes are created but they don't have any items.

Comment: It's not an SAP question, it's a question about why your program is unable to handle the XML response returned by SAP (which seems to be a valid XML syntax).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I came in this morning and tested the Web-services and hey presto it now works.

I've changed nothing so I asked the SAP people if they had an explanation and this is it:

> Yesterday I made changes to RFC like structure type to get the result into the table too using web service.

I'm not sure if that is going to be useful to anything...I'm just glad that it's finally working!

Comment: So the webservice now returns an XML that your program can interpret. It doesn't clarify why you had an issue with the original XML (which seems to be a valid XML syntax).